# How to remove System.out.print statements with Proguard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

I want to remove all print statements with **proguard**. Is there an equaivilent to the code below but for `System.out.println()`

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
}
```

Comment: The better way is using a Logger and just controlling the log level.

Answer (score 9):

For removing all `System.out.println`, you can add following in your rules.

```
-assumenosideeffects class java.io.PrintStream {
     public void println(%);
     public void println(**);
 }
```