# How to remove System.out println() while making release build in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am able to remove Log.d, Log.e etc by using proguard rules in android studio. But couldn't find any solution for system.out apart from manually commenting it.

Comment: Possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104775/how-to-remove-system-out-print-statements-with-proguard

Comment: Thanks. Found it. Have been searching for this for so long. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
-assumenosideeffects class java.io.PrintStream {
     public void println(%);
     public void println(**);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you can do something like this:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      // Code for debug release only
}
```

Comment: That has to be done in then whole project. I am looking for something like i added few lines in proguard rules to remove logs. In same manner is there something for system.out?